# ADF Parse Transformation with JSON

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have the following JSON object:

```
    {
    "comments_count": 0,
    "impressions": 2838,
    "lifetime_snapshot.followers_count": 14993,
    "likes": 10,
    "net_follower_growth": -3,
    "post_content_clicks": 19,
    "post_media_views": 415,
    "shares_count": 1,
    "video_views": 415
    }
```

In the Azure Data Factory Parse transformation I am creating a complex object with the following expression:

```
    (impressions as integer,
    likes as integer,
    comments_count as integer,
    lifetime_snapshot as (snap as (followers_count as integer)),
    net_follower_growth as integer,
    post_content_clicks as integer,
    post_media_views as integer,
    shares_count as integer,
    video_views as integer)
```

In the Data Preview tab I get all of the proper integer values except for the followers_count which is NULL.

What is the proper syntax to get the value for the lifetime_snapshot.followers_count field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this syntax:

```
(
    impressions as integer,
    likes as integer,
    comments_count as integer,
    {lifetime_snapshot.followers_count} as integer,
    net_follower_growth as integer,
    post_content_clicks as integer,
    post_media_views as integer,
    shares_count as integer,
    video_views as integer
)
```

Data Preview:

[image]